# How to get the URL of the parent from an iframe in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a page on the example.com domain which contains an IFrame, this IFrame loads an ASP.NET page (c#) from the example2.com domain.

From the code behind on the example2.com domain how can I get the URL of the master page?

Would it help if the 2 pages were on the same domain, so example.com contains an iframe with sub.example.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the parent frame you can send the url of the page to your from with querystring. You can call your page as...

```
mysite.com/innerIframePage.aspx?parentPageUrl=http://.....
```

This way you can get the url from your codebehind

Comment: this isn't going to work for me, thanks. I need to be able to check that the master page the iframe is embedded in is the correct one

Answer (score -1):

Being on a subdomain makes it possible, but you would have to set the `document.domain` property of the subdomain page to `"example.com"`, so that both have the same `document.domain`.

Then you can get the data by using `parent.location.href`, which you can then add as a value to a hidden or other field.

[source for document.domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)